# What is illegal or will make sure you don't get published?

Tags: fiction

I am writing a book based off experiences shared to me by others, their opinions on the matter, about things that are completely illegal in the United States.

This book would be very dark and descriptive in nature and would include things like rape, incest, and minors.

The story covers those experiences as one man's life while also pointing out the horrors and destruction of lives including his own, so while explaining some things it would be taken as writing in a positive supportive way followed by the real darkness it is and the damage it causes.

Would this even be legal to write about?  If it is not illegal, would it be unpublishable?

Comment: When you say you're writing about people's experiences with rape, incest, and paedophilia, do you mean you're writing about people who were *victims* of those crimes, or people who were *perpetrators*? If it's the former, you'll be fine; if it's the latter, the answer is going to be a *lot* more complicated.

Comment: Legal in which jurisdiction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Yes, living people can sue you** for defamation, exposure of privacy, libel, and probably many other things. Assuming you can afford the lawsuit, some deciding factors in court include how the story was presented (memoir or fiction), how easily the actual people can be discovered from the information, whether the story happened to *you* or you are re-telling it second-hand, the privacy of any victims (especially minors), how accurately the people are portrayed, also how IN-accurately the people are portrayed, and whether you can verify your claims with any evidence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question to answer, but here are some thoughts for further deliberation.

### Is it publishable?

If you look at what's published you might find genres such as crime and horror that might cover worse topics than yours. Murder for instance.

You ask if it's publishable. In these days of self-publishing I think the question is rather, is it sellable? And that's a hard question to answer. Provided your text has technical quality, I'd say voice and luck are two other factors that will determine if it's sellable or not. Though not necessarily the only ones.

The target audience is another. How are you writing the book? What kind of effect are you seeking in the reader? Would this be a larger or smaller percentage of a population? For instance, if the text is erotic in nature, or preaching hell and damnation, it will have a smaller target audience than if it takes a stance somewhere in between.

### Will it be legal?

First off, I am not a lawyer, this is not a law forum, etc, etc. In essence, you should probably ask a real lawyer about the legality of the text...

In a democracy with sufficient freedom of speech, writing about rape, incest and pedophilia will not be illegal (see further discussion below, though)... as the saying goes, as long as no children, animals, or dolphins were hurt during the production of the text, you should be ok. However the court of public opinion might feel differently... but then again, sometimes important art will be hated by the public.

However, there are a few potential red flags in your question.

You mention this story is based on things told to you by other people. Can these people be identified in the text? Do they know you're writing this text? Do they want you to write the text? Did they give you their consent?

You may still be able to publish the book unless you're these people's therapist or otherwise a person that they should be able to expect confidentiality from. But you may lose some friends.

The perpetrators of these crimes, can they be identified? Are their real names used? Have they been found guilty in a court of law or is this book a standalone accusation of them? Do you trust the people that told you these stories and that they did in fact experience this? If this has not been dealt with in a court of law or reported to the police, do you know why?

You may want to make really sure the perpetrators cannot be identified unless you want to deal with defamation lawsuits. The same could go for the victims.

Of course, the best way to do that is to really make this come off as a fictional piece, for instance by changing not only names, places, and the order/timeline of things, but also by mixing and matching these aspects of the text, creating characters that are composites of several people, as well as places, and events.

Usually, when you start diving into aspects of the text such as theme, character arcs, story structure, and the like, you'll find that these changes make sense and will improve the quality of the story.

Sometimes you might need changes like moving the story from one end of the country to another or from one century to another only to get the vitamin injection the story and your process needed to get back on track.

**Update**: It's worth stressing that the above advice about mixing and matching is of course only valid for fictional works. If your genre is not fictional, staying as close as possible to the truth is obviously important.